# Access - Do Not Query Subform When Parentform is Opened

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have an MS Access form, that contains a subform whose recordset is a query that takes quite a while to process and isn't actually needed right away when the parentform is opened, but only after a button on the form is pressed.

Is there a way to implement this with VBA other then completely changing the form with something like Set Me.MySubForm.Form.Recordset = NULL? I've tried Me.MySubForm.Enabled = False but that doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way:

Leave the `SourceObject` property of the subform control empty. Then when the button is pressed, do

```
Me.MySubForm.SourceObject = "mySubFormName"
```

This way the subform and its data isn't loaded until needed.

Comment: Thank's for the answer! This really seems like the easiest option.